# Angular Service test not passing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine, angular-services

I have a service which uses a json-server to act as my database. I can confirm that my service works as I can return my response in a component. But I'm having such issues trying to get a Jasmin unit test to work.

### This is my receipt-data-public.spec.ts file

```js
import { ReceiptsDataPublic } from './receipts-data-public';
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Receipt } from '../classes/receipt';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('ReceiptsDataPublic', () => {
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let service: ReceiptsDataPublic;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ReceiptsDataPublic],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });

    // We inject our service (which imports the HttpClient) and the Test Controller
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(ReceiptsDataPublic);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get(ReceiptsDataPublic);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call getDevReceipts', () => {
    const serviceSpy = spyOn(service as ReceiptsDataPublic, 'getDevReceipts');
    service.getDevReceipts();
    expect(serviceSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should call getReceipts', () => {
    const serviceSpy = spyOn(service as ReceiptsDataPublic, 'getReceipts');
    service.getReceipts();
    expect(serviceSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  });

  it('returned Observable should match the right data', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const receipt = {
      id: 1,
      expenseDate: "2019-04-26T15:15:56.948Z",
      description: "Id cupiditate sint et dolores molestias consequuntur necessitatibus ipsa. Qui assumenda consequuntur enim cumque eos eligendi culpa sit aspernatur. Qui molestiae voluptate sed a mollitia voluptatem rerum. Neque accusamus voluptate iusto vero illo consequuntur. Et ut at quod tenetur veritatis recusandae quia sed. Perspiciatis ipsum consequuntur neque distinctio.",
      amount: 122.00,
      imgUrl:"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?product"
    };

    service.getDevReceipts()
      .subscribe(res => {
        expect(res[0].amount).toEqual(12.9);
        done();
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://localhost:3000/receipts');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(receipt);
  });
});
```

### Here is my actual receipt-data-public.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReceiptsDataService } from './receipts-data.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Receipt } from '../classes/receipt';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ReceiptsDataPublic implements ReceiptsDataService {
  private LOCAL_REST_API_SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000/receipts';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = 'Unknown error!';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  getDevReceipts(): Observable<Receipt[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Receipt[]>(this.LOCAL_REST_API_SERVER);
  }

  getReceipts(): Observable<Receipt[]> {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

But I keep getting the below:

[image: Karma failed test]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as I'm following the Angular documentation? How can I set up my service test to test for returning the data, and matching it against the receipt data?

When I change to the subscribe function instead of toPromise() I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined thrown

Comment: Your service expects an array from the api but you flush `req.flush(receipt);` which is not an array. It seems like there is a mistake there

Comment: Oh right, do I need to say have an array of receipt objects which will allow me to match the objects? I'm going to give this a go! When I was in the subscribe, I couldn't log the response. Would the flush be an effect of this also?

Comment: `res[0].amount` throws an exception. This might be the reason. Could you try this `req.flush([receipt])`?

Comment: The flush change worked! I'm both very happy that it worked by annoyed I couldn't get there but now I learned! How come it doesn't take the response from the service but takes the receipt object? If I change the receipt.amount, I see that is what the expect it matching on. But in my local data, the amount is different? Also thank you for your help! That was really bugging me!

Comment: I'll post an answer

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'll finish it tomorrow morning and of I can sort it I'll take it! Thanks

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'll finish it tomorrow morning and of I can sort it I'll take it! Thanks

Comment: Posted an answer, check it out and let me know if it clears everything for you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are flushing an object from mock `HttpClient` instead of an array.

What you should do is simply change

`req.flush(receipt);`

to

`req.flush([receipt]);`

The pitfall you fell into is the return type of the service. Always be aware of that types are only there for development purposes and do not exist during runtime. Marking your return type as `Observable<Receipt[]>` does not guarantee that you will get an `Observable` of `Receipt[]` when you run the code. I assume your code runs perfectly because your backend returns an array of `Receipt`. It does not work the same in the test because you flush an simple object instead of an array. During tests, `req.flush` becomes your backend service. So whatever you put in `req.flush`, your service will return that even if it is completely something else than `Receipt[]`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it and it certainly cleared it. Also, your answer was very informative and I learned a lot from it. Can I ask though, I was expecting my response to return an amount of 830.00, can you only test the object you created like in my case "receipt"? Res[0].amount should be 830.00 so it shouldn't pass?